# Avg Network Out evaluation for auto scaling

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, autoscaling, network-monitoring

I have created **Elastic beanstalk environment** with **postgresql RDS**. The auto scaling system boots a new instance based on default auto scaling trigger attached to the environment i.e. **Avg NetworkOut** >= 6MB, in last 5 min. I have following 2 queries related to this.

1. How to evaluate an appropriate value of this trigger for my Django application ?
2. As per my observation auto scaling threshold exceeds whenever a cron script runs, now I am not able to figure out what part of this cron script should I optimize to not exceed the Avg NetworkOut thresh hold. This script basically performs following actions on ~10,000 records:
   a. Bunch of database calls (RDS)
   b. Call Google Map API
   c. Call GCM API
   How to calculate which of following actions are participating most to exceed the Avg Network Out thresh hold ? so that I can optimize that.

Comment: Why not move the cron job to a separate instance ? (min/max 1 ASG). It's rather silly to have a metric by which you scale out being influenced by a cron job.

Comment: @Dennis accepted, but given the scenario we are not allowed to boot new instance for cron, how to handle these queries ?

Comment: You could consider Lambda + SQS if an additional instance really isn't an option.